# Nonnegativity on a special domain entails nonnegativity on the whole plane

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Let $Q$ be a real bivariate polynomial such that $Q(x,\tan(x))\geq 0$
for any $x\not\in\{\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\}+(2\pi){\mathbb Z}$. Does it
necessarily follow that $Q$ is nonnegative on the whole of ${\mathbb R}^2$ ?

It is known that there is no non-trivial algebraic identity relating
$x$ to $\tan(x)$, and that makes me think that the answer is YES.

Comment: Would not $Q(x,y) = x^2+(y-1)^2-\epsilon$ be a counterexample?